# Javascript File Handling

Tags: javascript, onload, filereader

I am trying to load a client side text file using drag and drop. I've been looking at the example code and tutorials here:
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/
and here
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Everything works correctly up until the reader.onload event.

```
function handleFiles(files) 
{
var file = files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

//create function to deal with the file once it is loaded 
reader.onload = handleLoadedFile();

// begin the read operation
reader.readAsText(file);

}

function handleLoadedFile(event)
{
alert(event.target.result);
}
```

I thought the text should be in event.target.result but it's not! The alert doesn't fire.

Comment: ...then what happens?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: if you supply a fiddle ill take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
//create function to deal with the file once it is loaded 
reader.onload = handleLoadedFile();
```

you should write

```
//store reference to function to deal with the file once it is loaded 
reader.onload = handleLoadedFile;
```

Explanation:

When writing `eventhandler = afunction()` the eventhandler stores the result of the function, in your case this is `undefined`, since your handleLoadedFile does not return anything.

In case of `eventhandler = afunction` the function is not evaluated at the time of setting the handler. Only a reference to the function is stored. At the time the event fires, the stored reference will be evaluated with the `()` operator (probably this is not really the correct name, but you can at least think of `()` beeing an operator).

BTW this is a mistake which is made by experienced JavaScript programmers quite often. And there are cases where this is correct, e.g.:

```
reader.onload = createEventListener('success');
reader.onerror = createEventListener('error');

function createEventListener(type) {
    return function(event) {
        var content;
        if (type === 'success') {
            content = processMyFile(event.target.result);
        } else {
            content = 'An Error occurred. Please try another file.';
        }
        $('#content').html(content);
    }
}
```

So you can see it is not wrong in all cases not to use `()` when setting an event handler. I hope I didn't confuse you too much, since the construct above contains a powerful language feature of JavaScript (namely [Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)) which takes some time to be well understood.

FYI: There are other ways to call a function when you have a reference to it: [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) just to avoid down-votes from the JavaScript gurus ;-)

Additional hint: Please never use `alert()` for debugging your code. When testing with modern browsers (Internet Explorer < 11 should be avoided) you have a much better way to trace your code: `console.log()` and other methods of `console`. You'll love to use it because you don't have to click the OK button and you don't change the behaviour of your asynchronous operations as dramatically as with `alert`. Read [Mastering Console Logging](http://dailyjs.com/2012/02/02/console/) and play around with it - you'll never look back to alert!